# Running a program in windows with a specific name, so that I can close it mid run later

Tags: python, windows

I open many instances of the same program on windows, and many run simultaneously.  Sometimes, something goes wrong with one of them, either its run time is too long, or it is taking up too much CPU and slowing everything else down, etc.  In those instances, I want to shut the instance down, so that it doesn't get in the way, and run it again at some other time.

To accomplish this, I was thinking that maybe I could open the programs (just as i do now), but with a specific name.  An example might be, PythonProg1, PythonProg2, etc.  As the program runs, if something goes wrong, then I can shut down the specific instance that I want to shut down by ending that named instance.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neil - are you opening them up by clicking on them?  If that is the case, I don't think I can help you.

If you have a python script to run them, then it is simply a matter of assigning each one to a variable as you start it...

```
PythonProg1 = Popen(...
```

You could even just keep a list of them...

```
PythonProg = []
PythonProg.add(Popen(...))
```

You could then put in a timer or other test criteria and run Popen.kill() against any offenders.

Comment: Thanks.  Right now I am using windows scheduler to run them, but am thinking about switching to opening them from an admin program instead, and am just trying to plan out how I will do this right now.  I will test out your solution.  Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Paul, do you have any idea how I could also give the program a temporary name that Windows itself recognized (For example in the task manager).  I would like to keep track of the particular program's CPU usage, RAM, etc.  If I could make Windows recognize each instance by a separate name, I could get that kind of data pretty easily, but if Windows cannot uniquely identify particular instances, I don't know if it will be possible to identify unique instances that are causing bottlenecks and other problems.

Comment: To be clearer, lets say I run a program called PythonProgram.  If I run 20 instances, and later ask windows what the CPU usage of PythonProgram is, i would either get an aggregate number, or a list of numbers, but I would not be able to identify which instance was causing trouble.  But, if Windows recognized each by a unique name, PythonProgram1, for example, I could find out CPU usage for that particular program (using psutil i think).

Comment: Neil, each subprocess can access the PID of the spawned process- Popen.pid is the field.  There is at least one module that you can use to get info about a PID such as memory usage.  You could run a loop that adds processes until there are a certain number, then checks the status of each one and kills it if it meets your criteria.